# How to pass data to Custom ESLint rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

I have written a custom ESLint rule as follows:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Rule Definition
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
module.exports = {
    meta: {
        type: "suggestion",
        docs: {
            description: "Test Description",
            category: "Common",
            recommended: true,
            url: ""
        },
        fixable: "code",
        schema: [] // no options
    },
    create: function (context) {
        return {
            ClassDeclaration(node) {
            var data = ""// I want to pass value here from CMD
                if (node.id.name === data)
                {
                    context.report({
                                node: node,
                                message: "ESLint rule triggered"
                            });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am running ESLint for a Test.js file using following command in CMD.

```
npx eslint Test.js
```

Is there a way in which I can pass data to the rule from CMD while executing eslint command?
I want to pass a value to the variable '**data**' from

Comment: Are you trying to match an arbitrary node, by name? Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: No. I just want to use the data passed from CMD command in ESLint Custom Rule. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with [Node.js environment variables](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs). [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) includes environment variables you set manually:

```bash
EXAMPLE=abc123 npx eslint Test.js
```

```js
// in your rule file
console.log(process.env.EXAMPLE);
```

You might also consider using [rule options set in the ESLint config](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules#accessing-options-passed-to-a-rule). Those can be set with environment variables, too.

> *(if you're on a Windows bash prompt, see [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to set `EXAMPLE=abc123`)*